# Force webpage to open outside facebook

Tags: facebook, redirect, external

I don't want my webpage to open inside facebook. It doesn't function quite right.

Is there a way to list a url that when reached, redirects to my external site that is NOT is the facebook interface?

I have tried uploading a php file with a redirect in it, but it makes no difference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.top.location.href = "http://aurumhairstylists.co.nz";
</script>
<p>If you are not automatically redirected here is a link to <a target="_blank" href="http://shereewalker.com">shereewalker.com</a>.  Opens in a new tab or window.</p>
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IT is possible but the browser would block the page as a action not "requested by the user".

this is a VERY simple implementation:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("http://aurumhairstylists.co.nz", "myWindow", "width=400, height=200");
}
</script>
<IMG SRC="1x1.gif" ALT="" HEIGHT=1 WIDTH=1 onLoad="myFunction()">
```

cheers

Comment: Would this go in the php file I have stored on my site? It does not seem to work. Sorry!

Comment: it doesnt work because you have to point the image to a real image, this was just an example. this code would replace yours

Comment: I'm sorry but where does the image come into it? Basically if someone follows my link to my website in a Facebook post, I want to force it to open outside of Facebook. So it would be a link they are following rather than an image. Thanks

Comment: if you look at the script, the image is that "triggers" the script to open a new window. As iI said before it wont quite work just because browsers will block that request